# How to set max height of a picture in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to set maximal height of a picture in crystal report and preserve original ratio of a picture?
If can grow is disabled, every picture is streched or shrinked to default picture object size, if is enabled, I'm losing limits of picture size.
I'm using crystal reports for VS 2013 (13.0.5)

Comment: In RDC COM component (I don't know your options, thereby only comment here) we are using section format events to manually set picture dimensions. It is not nice workaround and behaves differently on different CR versions - but as far our code uses strictly CR9 runtime, it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No. I did many tests and researches and I didn't found any way to control the height and, without controlling the height, it's not possible to fit an arbitrary image in the object box and keep is ratio at the same time.

Looks like it's and old [problem](https://ideas.sap.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=A5E8DEA8-D886-4250-BA2B-039F7D32FFC0&idea_id=97CF50F7-AD6E-48C1-AA62-7C180D3EEF3E).

But if all your images are limited to the same dimensions, like you have set your limits to 500x500, so you can have, for example, images that do 500x200, 500x500, 250x500, etc., there's a way to do it.

The object box needs to have the same ratio as your limits. In my example, 500x500, the ratio is 1:1 (square) so your object box needs to be square also. You need to check `Can grow` and, in the Image tab, set the size exactly like the object box's size. You also have to set the bitmap image size (right-click on the box, choose *Bitmap Image Object* then *Modify*) to the image limits (500x500).

Comment: I know, that's sad... Common solution is to resize every images outside of Crystal. What a waste of ressources.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I solved this problem for Visual Basic 5.0 and Crystal Reports 6.0 (Seagate version). You asked the newer version but maybe this gives you an idea to solve the problem or it may help some other guys searching an answer for their problems.

Before you assign the report source you can change the height of the picture:

```
Set crxFieldObject = Report.Sections.Item("D").ReportObjects.Item(269)
crxFieldObject.Height = theNewHeight
CRViewer1.ReportSource = Report
CRViewer1.ViewReport
```

PS: After you assign the report source you can not change the height property. Below code does NOT work:

```
Private Sub Section3_Format(ByVal pFormattingInfo As Object)
     Picture1.Height = theNewHeight 'this code does NOT work
End Sub
```

In this code:

`.Sections.Item("D")`means the Detail Section of the report and

`.Item(269)` means the Picture Object. After you insert an OLE Object you can check the item number with a small code such as:

```
aa = Report.Sections.Item("D").ReportObjects.Count
For i = 1 To aa
    Set crxFieldObject = Report.Sections.Item("D").ReportObjects.Item(i)
    bb = crxFieldObject.Name
    If Mid(bb, 1, 7) = "Picture" Then
        crxFieldObject.suppress = False 'You can put a BreakPoint here to check the value of i
    End If
Next i
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow steam punk! :)

Comment: @dllhell Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too late, but when you right click on picture -> shaping of the object
You've a checkbox "modular size", uncheck it and put manually the size you want on Image tab.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Crystal Developer 11

1. add an image that you point to a folder + file name (file name is from database and folder is fixed)
2. create the image at the desired size
3. do not click the "can grow"
   Once the images load up, if they fit the image area they will be shown with the proper aspect ratio, if they are larger then they will be scaled down automatically to have the size fit in the image area

Note: if the image is way to small then the aspect ratio is compromised, but if image is big enough (like half the page or full page) then ratio is correct